# How to cast an object in sqlite as only Date and pass date from a parameterised query

Tags: sqlite

So I'm trying to check if some of my values match, for that I'm using an SQLite object and casting it as date and passing it as a parameter which is also a Date, I just want to know if this is the right way to do it?

```
       "AND R1.TIMING = ?
    AND R1.VARIETY = ?
    AND R1.JOBACRES = ?
    AND CAST (R1.PLANTINGDATE AS DATE) = ?
new object[] { item.TIMING, item.VARIETY, item.JOBACRES, item.PLANTINGDATE.Date }).ToList();
```

This is written in C#, since I want to execute this query in C# with SQLite, any inputs would be helpful

Comment: There is no DATE data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @forpas any idea as to how we can make it work the above requirement ?

Comment: There is no need to do anything if you store the dates in PLANTINGDATE as text in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+compare+date+only+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @forpas so that would basically mean we compare text, is it possible to format the object into the your mentioned format ?

Comment: You could search for SQLite Date And Time Functions for more details.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT yes i got it to work